# Migrate my users ERC1155 tokens to ERC721

Tags: solidity, hardhat, opensea, erc721

I have my ERC1155 token contract deployed on Ethereum network
i want my token holders to make the token to 721 standard and burn the old tokens
how can i achieve that using a proxy contract
need some proper direction on this , thanks

So looking to migrate the OpenSea ERC1155 tokens to the new ERC721 tokens. The existing contract has 135 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

a proxy contract won't let you do this migration for a couple of reasons, first a proxy contract just let you update the address of the contract where the actual logic is, but it has some limitations, like that the proxy contract should be deployed from the beginning you can't just deploy a proxy an expect that it changes or modify an existing contract, but let's say you have an upgreadable erc1155, for the limitation of the proxy you will probably have a lot of problems doing this update, because you can't change the way that the variables are defined or stored, you can't delete any existing function (you can leave it empty instead),and other things

probably you will need to deploy a new contract that will be the erc721, then you will have to make another contract that makes the swap, receive a token from the old contract and gives the token of the new contract, is on you how the contract will get the new tokens if it will mint the tokens or if it will have it, also you have to considere what you will do with the old tokens because if the old contract do not let the tokens to be burned you can't, but you could lock it in the same contract or something similar that is almost the same as burning it